# minimizing the sum with a lower bound on the product

Tags: algorithm, primes, mathematical-optimization

I have an optimization problem that I'm currently solving by brute force, but I'm hoping there is a better way.

**Problem**: Given `n` and `d`, find prime powers `p1^e1, ..., pk^ek` (`pi`s are distinct) such that

1. `p1^e1 * ... * pk^ek >= n^d`
2. `p1^e1 + ... + pk^ek < n` is minimal

My current solution is to iterate through all possible subsets of primes (up to some fixed number), then iterate through all possible exponents (up to some fixed number), then test condition 1, then see if the sum is the smallest so far. This takes a really long time. Is there something more clever that I can do to speed this up?

Comment: This is not from Project Euler, is it?

Comment: @angelatlarge No. It's not homework, either.

Comment: This seems like a [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). I suspect it is NP-complete. In fact, if (d = 1), an *optimization* might be equivalent to factoring.

Comment: @BrettHale That's very helpful. Turn your comment into an answer so I can vote it up (and possibly accept it, since I think you're right about the Knapsack analogy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). I suspect it is NP-complete. In fact, if (d = 1), an *optimization* might be equivalent to factoring.

Not all Knapsack problems are NP-hard however - which is why the Merkle–Hellman knapsack cryptosystem was broken.

Comment: Optimization for `d=1` is **not** factoring, e.g. `n=1000 = 2^3 * 5^3` and `2^3 + 5^3 = 133`, but `2^2 * 3^3 * 5 * 7 = 1260` and `2^2 + 3^2 + 5 + 7 = 25`.

Comment: Definitely looks like knapsack is right to me; the dynamic programming example on the link you gave speeds things up tremendously. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By the AM-GM inequality and using the other constraints you can get:

(n / k)^k > product >= n^d

Hence n^(k-d) > k^k. Taking log to base n we get:
k-d > k*log(k). Since k <= n ( based on the sum)
k * (1 - log(k)) > d

You can plot the LHS above to get an estimate of k.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me. The number of prime powers `k` depends on the choice of prime powers, and the sum is always <= the product.

Comment: Yes the first inequality was not to have sum. It was supposed to be (sum / k)^k >= product which is what the AM-GM inequality is. I have fixed that now

Comment: Ok, but this still doesn't make any sense and doesn't begin to address my question. I'm looking for the prime powers and I don't much care how many there are (which is what `k` counts).

Comment: Also, this has nothing to do with algebraic or geometric means, and the inequality you state, `(n/k)^k >= n^d` is blatantly false.

Comment: I would suggest you read up on the inequality if you wish to know if the above argument is true or false. I don't wish to devote much more time to explaining fundamental mathematical facts.

Comment: Assuming that both constraints are satisfied, (n/k)^k >= n^d follows as given above, although the details are not worked out clearly. Still this does not solve the problem, but it gives a condition on k that might speed up the search, whatever algorithm you follow.